# How do I stop the code from repeating the same calculation and instead have a random calculation each time

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have to make a program where I have to ask the user for a number which I would add to a randomly generated value. If the total sum is over 50 then the loop should break however if it's not then it should generate a new value and add it to the user input until it goes over 50

My code:

```
import random
i = random.randint(1, 50)

num = input("Please enter a number: ")

while i <= 50:
    total = i + int(num)
    print("The total is " + str(total))
    if total > 50:
        break
```

The code works fine when the total is over 50 but if it's not then it would keep repeating the same line infinitely

Desired result:

```
Please enter a number: 23
Your total is 41
Your total is 35
Your total is 63     <------ The code would break here since it's over 50
```

My actual result:

```
Please enter a number: 36
Your total is 44
Your total is 44
Your total is 44
Your total is 44
Your total is 44
Your total is 44
Your total is 44
Your total is 44
Your total is 44


This will keep repeating
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're not actually updating total.  Your while test is also not actually performing anything useful here.  You can replace it with while True or with while total <= 50.

```
import random

i = random.randint(1, 50)
num = input("Please enter a number:\n>>> ")
total = int(num)
while True:
    total += i
    print("The total is", total)
    if total > 50:
        break

print('done')
```

Now, are you actually intending to add the same number every time?  I suspect not, but maybe.  If you intend to add a new random number every time, this is what you might have meant to do:

```
import random

num = input("Please enter a number:\n>>> ")
total = int(num)

while total <= 50:
    total += random.randint(1, 50)
    print("The total is", total)

print('done')
```

Answer (score 1):

You should initialize `total` outside the loop, and generate a random number inside `while` each time the number is less than `50`:

```
import random
total = 0
i = random.randint(1, 50)
print('Generated random number:', i)
total += i


while i <= 50:
    print("The total is " + str(total))
    if total > 50:
        print('Total Exceeded 50!!!')
        break
    else:
        j = random.randint(1, 50)
        total +=j
        print('Generated random number:', i)
```